# How can I save any changes of containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud

If I have one ubuntu container and I ssh to it and make one file after the container is destroyed or I reboot the container the new file was destroyed because the kubernetes load the ubuntu image that does not contain my changes.
My question is what should I do to **save any changes**?
I know **it can be done** because some cloud provider do that.

For example:

```
ssh ubuntu@POD_IP
mkdir new_file
ls 
  new_file
reboot
```

after reboot I have

```
ssh ubuntu@POD_IP
ls
```

`ls` shows nothing

But I want to it save my current state.
And I want to do it **automatically**.

If I use docker commit I can not control my images because it makes hundreds of images. because I should make images by every changes.

If **I want to use storage** I should **mount /**. but kubernetes does not allow me to mount /. and it gives me this error

> Error: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/var/lib/kubelet/pods/26c39eeb-85d7-11e9-933c-7c8bca006fec/volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/pvc-d66d9039-853d-11e9-8aa3-7c8bca006fec:/': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'

Comment: Can you not use volumes? I don't know kubernetes I'm afraid so maybe I'm mistaken here.

Comment: If i do not use volume my new changes do not save and after reboot they destroy

Comment: I'm telling you should use them, I'm not telling you you shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `docker commit` but you will need to ensure that your Kubernetes cluster is picking up the latest image that you committed -

`docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]`

This is going to create a new image out of your container which you can feed to Kubernetes.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

**Update 1** -

In case you want to do it automatically, you might need to store the changed state or the files at a centralized file system like NFS etc & then mount it to all running containers whenever required with the relevant permissions.

K8s ref - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

Comment: If I use docker commit I can not control my images because it makes hundreds of images.because i should make images  by every changes .

Comment: If I want to use storage i should mount /. but kubernetes does not allow me to mount /. and it gives me this error

Error: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/var/lib/kubelet/pods/26c39eeb-85d7-11e9-933c-7c8bca006fec/volumes/kubernetes.io~rbd/pvc-d66d9039-853d-11e9-8aa3-7c8bca006fec:/': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'

Comment: That's another problem. You need to build your image in a way so that it writes to a specific dir which is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Docker and Kubernetes don't work this way.  Never run `docker commit`.  Usually you have very little need for an ssh daemon in a container/pod and you need to do special work to make both the sshd and the main process both run (and extra work to make the sshd actually be secure); your containers will be simpler and safer if you just remove these.

The usual process involves a technique known as *immutable infrastructure*.  You never change code in an existing container; instead, you change a recipe to build a container, and tell the cluster manager that you want an update, and it will tear down and rebuild everything from scratch.  To make changes in an application running in a Kubernetes pod, you typically:

1. Make and test your code change, locally, with no Docker or Kubernetes involved at all.
2. `docker build` a new image incorporating your code change.  It should have a unique tag, often a date stamp or a source control commit ID.
3. (optional but recommended) `docker run` that image locally and run integration tests.
4. `docker push` the image to a registry.
5. Change the image tag in your Kubernetes deployment spec and `kubectl apply` (or `helm upgrade`) it.

Often you'll have an automated *continuous integration* system do steps 2-4, and a *continuous deployment* system do the last step; you just need to commit and push your tested change.

Note that when you `docker run` the image locally in step 3, you are running the exact same image your production Kubernetes system will run.  Resist the temptation to mount your local source tree into it and try to do development there!  If a test fails at this point, reduce it to the simplest failing case, write a unit test for it, and fix it in your local tree.  Rebuilding an image shouldn't be especially expensive.

Your question hints at the unmodified [`ubuntu`](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) image.  Beyond some very early "hello world" type experimentation, there's pretty much no reason to use this anywhere other than the `FROM` line of a Dockerfile.  If you haven't yet, you should work through the [official Docker tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/), which will be applicable to any clustering system.  (Skip all of the later tutorials that cover Docker Swarm, if you've already settled on Kubernetes as an orchestrator.)